# Orion context broker doesn't create tenant databases "on the fly"

Tags: mongodb, fiware, fiware-orion

I created and ran fiware-iot-agent in docker container along with fiware-orion context broker. The mongoDb Im using is a sharded cluster with 2 shards and auth-enabled. I verified that orion is connecting to the cluster.
Below is the docker-compose.yml Im using.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  # Orion is the context broker
  orion:
    image: fiware/orion:${ORION_VERSION}
    hostname: orion
    container_name: fiware-orion-pms
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "${ORION_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${ORION_PORT}:${ORION_PORT}" # localhost:1026
    command: -dbhost 192.168.2.5:27030 -dbuser $DB_USER -dbpwd $DB_PWD -dbAuthDb admin  -db orion -logLevel DEBUG
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://orion:${ORION_PORT}/version || exit 1
      interval: 5s
    restart: always
    labels:
      maintainer: ino
      description: fiware-orion
      project: pms
      version: v1.0.0
      type: fiware

  # IoT-Agent is configured for the UltraLight Protocol
  #
  # This deliberately fixed to v1.7.0
  # see: https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/issues/320
  #
  # For v1.8 and v1.9 a dummy resource must be added when provisioning
  #
  iot-agent:
    image: fiware/iotagent-json
    hostname: iot-agent
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent-pms
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}:${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}" # localhost:4041
    environment:
      - IOTA_CB_HOST=orion # name of the context broker to update context
      - IOTA_CB_PORT=1026 # port the context broker listens on to update context
      - IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041
      - IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb #Whether to hold IoT device info in memory or in a database
      - IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=FATAL # The log level of the IoT Agent
      - IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true # Supply timestamp information with each measurement
      - IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2 # use NGSIv2 when sending updates for active attributes
      - IOTA_AUTOCAST=true # Ensure Ultralight number values are read as numbers not strings
      - IOTA_MONGO_USER=$DB_USER 
      - IOTA_MONGO_PASSWORD=$DB_PWD
      - IOTA_MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE=admin  
      - IOTA_MONGO_HOST=192.168.2.5 # The host name of MongoDB
      - IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27030 # The port mongoDB is listening on
      - IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentul # The name of the database used in mongoDB
      - IOTA_MQTT_HOST=192.168.2.10 # The host name of the MQTT Broker
      - IOTA_MQTT_PORT=1883 # The port the MQTT Broker is listening on to receive topics
      - IOTA_DEFAULT_RESOURCE= # Default is blank. I'm using MQTT so I don't need a resource
      - IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent:${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}
      - IOTA_DEFAULT_TRANSPORT=MQTT
    healthcheck:
      interval: 5s
    restart: always
    labels:
      maintainer: ino
      description: fiware-orion-agent-json
      project: pms
      version: v1.0.0
      type: fiware

networks:
  default:
    labels:
      org.fiware: 'fiware-networks-pms'
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.50.1.0/24
```

My problem is when I add a new device to the fiware using endpoint `http://localhost:4041/iot/devices` it creates a database named iotagentul and a collection named devices in it. The device I added is being saved to this collection. So far so good. But Im expecting another database to be created when I add a new device. In orion docs it says this:

> Normally, Orion Context Broker uses just one database at MongoDB level (the one specified with the -db command line option, typically "orion"). However, when multitenant/multiservice is used the behaviour is different and the following databases are used (let  be the value of the -db command line option): The database  for the default tenant (typically, orion) The database - for service/tenant  (e.g. **if the tenant is named tenantA and default -db is used, then the database would be orion-tenantA. Per-service/tenant databases are created "on the fly" as the first request involving tenant data is processed by Orion.** Finally, in the case of per-service/tenant databases, all collections and administrative procedures (backup, restore, etc.) are associated to each particular service/tenant database.

So according to this there should be other databases which will hold the entities for the devices. But they are not showing up. I tried with a mongo without authorization but its still same. How can I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: My request body is shown below:

```
    {
 "devices": [
   {
     "device_id": "PA_TALASLI1",
     "entity_name": "PA_TALASLI1",
     "entity_type": "power_analysis",
     "transport":   "HTTP",
     "timezone":    "Europe/Istanbul",
     "attributes": [
       { "object_id": "Voltage_UL1_N", "name":"Voltage_UL1_N", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Voltage_UL2_N", "name":"Voltage_UL2_N", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Voltage_UL3_N", "name":"Voltage_UL3_N", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Current_L1", "name":"Current_L1", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Current_L2", "name":"Current_L2", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Current_L3", "name":"Current_L3", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Total_Active_Power", "name":"Total_Active_Power", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Total_Reactive_Power", "name":"Total_Reactive_Power", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Total_Power_Factor", "name":"Total_Power_Factor", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Total_Active_Energy_IN_T1", "name":"Total_Active_Energy_IN_T1", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Total_Active_Energy_IN_T2", "name":"Total_Active_Energy_IN_T2", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Total_Active_Energy_EX_T1", "name":"Total_Active_Energy_EX_T1", "type":"Double"},
       { "object_id": "Total_Active_Energy_EX_T2", "name":"Total_Active_Energy_EX_T2", "type":"Double"}
      ],
      "lazy":[
        { "object_id": "Voltage_UL1_N", "name":"Voltage_UL1_N", "type":"Double"}
      ],
      "static_attributes": [
         {"name":"refStore", "type": "Relationship","value": "urn:ngsi-ld:pa_talasli1:001"}
      ]
   }
 ]
}
```

I tried running the container with log level debug but I didnt see anything about the entity creation. If I add a *lazy* attribute to the body, it creates a table named *registerations* but there is no entities table. I specifically created an entity through `/v2/entities/` but what I need is to have entities be created after I add a new device to `/iot/devices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found why fiware-iot-agent wasnt able to create entities collection. **When I add a new device, there has to be some data being published from that device via MQTT**. The collection is being created after first data is being published. The reason I was expecting entities to be created right after adding a new device was because I was misled by my 'senior' team-leader. She told me over and over if I add a new device I'd be able to create that collection.

Comment: In the past it worked that way (i.e. entity was created at device provision time), but that changes in IOTA Lib 3.4.0 (which is the one used by IOTA JSON 2.4.0). Maybe your senior team-leader is not aware of recent IOTAs evolution ;) So I guess you are using IOTA JSON 2.4.0 or beyond (note in your question post you don't tell which specific versions are you using... or I have missed it)

Comment: This documentation PR (to be merged at some moment) provides additional clarification on this: https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/pull/1551/files (section "Device autoprovision and entity creation").

Comment: @fgalan Thanks for the answer. To be honest I didn't think about inspecting these. I just looked over the issues about entities but couldn't find anything. In the compose we're directly pulling the latest image of fiware-iotagent and 3.7 version of the orion cb. About my team leader, she was referring to her 10 months old experiences, saying it was working then. I made sure she saw that.

Answer (score 0):

Orion doesn't use tenants BY DEFAULT. You have to tell it to, by using the CLI param `-multiservice` (at least that's how it worked some time ago).

Comment: In this link at end of the page, under the 4.4 it says *Orion will be running on multi-tenant mode* ```https://hub.docker.com/r/telefonicaiot/fiware-orion``` . I also tried to add that flag to the command section of the compose and I got an error saying something like duplicate -multiservice flag. Anyway I found the solution.